# Stuck with environmental variables

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu-14.04

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
Rails 4.2.5

In Ubuntu terminal I did:

```
1. FOOD2FORK_KEY="359c93f1c292c674d95237ca05fe87cc"
2. export FOOD2FORK_KEY
```

Now I can check:
set | grep FOOD2FORK_KEY

And get

```
FOOD2FORK_KEY=359c93f1c292c674d95237ca05fe87cc
_=FOOD2FORK_KEY
```

If in the terminal I launch irb and write:
puts ENV["FOOD2FORK_KEY"]||"It is nill"

I get:

```
359c93f1c292c674d95237ca05fe87cc
=> nil
```

But if I try to run a test.rb in Eclipse, I get "It is nill".
In other words, my project needs this environmental variable to be set.
But somehow I can't cope with this problem.

Could you help me understand what and why this environmental var acts like that? And how can I make it visible in my project?

Thank you in advande.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

- Add your environment variables to `/etc/environment` so they become persistent and system-wide available (more info here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)
- Add those environment variables in Eclipse project configuration (I don't use Eclipse, but it should be located in `Run -> Run Configurations... and Select tab "Environment"`

Answer (score 1):

Just to add an explanation of why you're seeing this behaviour:

When you `export` a variable it becomes visible to any [child processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_process). As you've launched `irb` from the shell in the terminal `irb` is a child of the shell so the value is visible. However, if you launch Eclipse separately e.g. from a different terminal or from the GUI then the value will not be visible from there.

[hugomarisco's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2811859/hugomarisco) suggestions are 2 good approaches to solving this.